# What is the complexity of determining whether a graph has a maximal clique of a given size?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

What is the complexity class of: given a graph G, is the graph has a maximal clique of size k? k is integer less than or equal the number of graph vertices.

A related question,

Given a Graph G, Find a maximal clique of size k. This is np because it is polynomially verifiable. Right?

The essential question if the above questions are np, then how to reduce them to the maximum clique problem, which is well-known np-complete problem?i.e. if we can find the maximum clique in polynomial time, how can we find a maximal clique of fixed size polynomially?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard NP-completeness reduction for Independent Set is from 3-SAT.  In this reduction, you there is an independent set of size $|C|$ where $C$ is the set of clauses, if and only if the 3-SAT instance is a yes-instance.  By construction, there cannot be any larger independent sets.

Therefore, you can trivially show that the *Maximal Independent Set* problem, i.e. Does $G$ have a maximal independent set of size $k$ is NP-complete in the same manner.

Now, proving similar results for clique should be effortless.

Comment: I know that, but that for independent set of a certain size which could be a subset of the maximum independent set; i.e. it is easily to reduce finding an independent set of a certain size to maximum independent set and vice versa by checking if the graph has an independent set of size n and less where n is the number of vertices so the complexity will be at worse  nO(n ^k) which is also polynomial assuming O(n^k) is the time required to find an independent set of a certain size. However my question is about a maximal independent set.

Comment: That comment doesn't make a lot of sense.  I think you need to work some more on reductions and hardness.  $n \cdot O(n^k)$ is certainly not polynomial in the normal setting.